# How do i test my asp.net httphandler

Tags: asp.net

Im trying to write a small web application for forwarding requests to my page to the new pages on my web site. First off im implementing a IHttpHandler and in the ProcessRequest method i simple want to print out the requesting page, my conde looks like this:

```
public class RedirectHandler : IHttpHandler
    {
        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get { return true; }
        }

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.Write(context.Request.Path);
        }
    }
```

I have registered in the web.config and have a problem with testing the handler. I start it through visual studio, it is just listing my files. I then from a browser request a file, and expects to see the name in the browser, but an exception that the page is not found is thrown. I have deleted all other .aspx page so the only "page" i have is my http handler. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

**Edit**
Configuration settings (web.config)

```
<system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <handlers>
      <add name="RedirectHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" verb="*" path="*.html" type="Jeeves.RedirectHandler"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Do you see any errors being logged to event log or anything like that?  Is it hitting your breakpoints even?

Comment: Its not hitting my breakpoint inside ProcessRequest, it is as its not running. I've started the project in debug and this results a directory listing of all the files. I cannot "run" any files, because the only file i got is RedirectHandler.cs

Comment: In your web config file change the path="*.html" attribute to another file extension such as *.ashx. Or for now set it to path="text.aspx" and then using a browser browse to this "page" that is http://localhost/someapp/test.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entries in the *system.webServer/handlers* configuration element are only effective if you are running IIS 7 (in *Integrated* mode).  Either specify *Use Local IIS Web Server*  in the *Web* section of the project's properties (if you have IIS7) **or** use the *system.web/httpHandlers* element instead:

```
<system.web>
   <httpHandlers>
       <add  verb="*" path="*.html" type="Jeeves.RedirectHandler"/>
   </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
```

Comment: I have tried everything. Running on IIs locally, did not work, build-in webserver in VS - did not work. Changed to asp.net MVC, in VS WebServer did not work, ASP.NEt MVC on IIS 7 - did not work. Guess i should wait a couple of days until my blood pressure is down again (from the agony) and try again... any suggestions are welcome...

Comment: If you're testing this in IIS then you may need to map .HTML to the asp.net isapi thingy so it's actually processed. Alternatively you could rename it to .ashx